# How to check if the tabSheet are already created in the TPageControl

Tags: delphi, tpagecontrol

I create the tabsheets dynamically in RunTime and placed a Frame inside it using this code:

```
  procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  TabSheetG: TTabSheet;
begin
  TabSheetG := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
  TabSheetG.Caption := 'Tab Sheet green  ';
  TabSheetG.PageControl := PageControl1;
  Frame3 := TFrame3.Create(nil);
  Frame3.Parent := TabSheetG;
  Frame3.Show;
end;
```

and now i want to knew if the tab are already created and just make it activate it when i click the same button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a private variable of type `TTabSheet` to your class.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ....
  private
    FMyTabSheet: TTabSheet;
  end;
```

It will automatically be initialized to `nil`.

In the `OnClick` event handler, test whether the variable is `nil`. If not, create the tabsheet, otherwise, use the existing tabsheet.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(FMyTabSheet) then
    FMyTabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
    FMyTabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;
    ... etc.
  end;
  PageControl1.ActivePage := FMyTabSheet;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks it's nice solution but do you think  it's functional if i got a 30 frame using 30 TabSheet?

Comment: Yes, it will scale just fine. You might well opt to declare a enumerated type for the 30 different pages. Then have an array of tab sheets and frames, indexed by that enumerated type.

Comment: I got i problem with his method , when i click the button the Tabsheet create just fine but when i close the Tabsheet it wont set to nil again so when i click the button again nothing happen because the TabSheet are not nill

Comment: When you remove the tabsheet, set the reference to nil.

Comment: It set dynamically, how i can do that in Designtime? i tired that on the Canclose event for the TpageControl but it set the reference to nil for all the Tabsheets on it. how to specify just the one i want to close?

Comment: I've no idea what your code looks like now. If you have code that destroys the tabsheet, set the reference to nil there.

Comment: What i meas is how to destroy a tabsheets dynamically created ?

Comment: Call `Free` on the tabsheet object

Comment: Yeah i knew but where? The Tabsheets has no events to do so?

Comment: You have to provide some UI to allow the user to close a page. What is it?

Comment: yes , i have to provide a littele close button on the tabsheet and when the user click on it , it should free and nil the tabsheet

Comment: So, what's the problem with doing that? Where are you stuck?